# Slick slider not showing first element

Tags: javascript, wordpress, slick.js

so I do struggle with the newest slick carousel implemented in a theme. This is how to JS looks like:

```
function slickSetup() {

    $(".swiper-container").each(function() {

      // Slick Variable
      var $ts = $(this);
      var $slickActive = $(this).find('.swiper-wrapper');
      var $sliderNumber = $(this).siblings('.slider-number');

      // Show Slider Number
      $slickActive.on('init reInit afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
        $sliderNumber.find('span').text(i);
        // $sliderNumber.find('b').text(slick.slideCount);
      });

      // Auto Play
      var autoPlayVar = parseInt($ts.attr('data-autoplay'), 10);
      // Auto Play Time Out
      var autoplaySpdVar = 3000;
      if (autoPlayVar > 1) {
        autoplaySpdVar = autoPlayVar;
        autoPlayVar = 1;
      }
      // Slide Change Speed
      var speedVar = parseInt($ts.attr('data-speed'), 10);
      // Slider Loop
      var loopVar = Boolean(parseInt($ts.attr('data-loop'), 10));
      // Slider Center
      var centerVar = Boolean(parseInt($ts.attr('data-center'), 10));
      // Pagination
      var paginaiton = $ts.children().hasClass('pagination');
      // Slide Per View
      var slidesPerView = $ts.attr('data-slides-per-view');
      if (slidesPerView == 1) {
        slidesPerView = 1;
      }
      if (slidesPerView == 'responsive') {
        var slidesPerView = parseInt($ts.attr('data-add-slides'), 10);
        var lgPoint = parseInt($ts.attr('data-lg-slides'), 10);
        var mdPoint = parseInt($ts.attr('data-md-slides'), 10);
        var smPoint = parseInt($ts.attr('data-sm-slides'), 10);
        var xsPoing = parseInt($ts.attr('data-xs-slides'), 10);
      }

      // Slick Active Code
      $slickActive.slick({
        autoplay: autoPlayVar,
        dots: paginaiton,
        centerPadding: '0',
        speed: speedVar,
        infinite: loopVar,
        autoplaySpeed: autoplaySpdVar,
        centerMode: centerVar,
        prevArrow: $ts.find('.swiper-arrow-left'),
        nextArrow: $ts.find('.swiper-arrow-right'),
        appendDots: $ts.find('.pagination'),
        slidesToShow: slidesPerView,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 1600,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: lgPoint
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1200,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: mdPoint
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 992,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: smPoint
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: xsPoing
            }
          }
        ],
        customPaging: function(slider, i) {
          $sliderNumber.find('b').text(i + 1);
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

What's the issue? No matter how many slides I've added it always skip the FIRST slide (I'm adding the pics via Wordpress). I've tried to change the images but the issue is still there. So I've figure out there might be an issue with a code responsible for selecting an active slide. The preview website is here: https://hardbox.vetcareers.eu/. The carousel is under the phrase "zaufali nam".

Comment: Hi, is this about that it is not showing first slide on initial? so it starts from "vege box" or is it that the first image is not even visible there?

Btw bardzo ładny strona, sama projektowałaś ? :)

Comment: @Sowam yes it's the first case! it's not visible at first glance, it starts from vege box, but if you will click and slide right, the true first slide will be revealed. thank you/dziekuje!:)